# Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [2788, 1813] I also tried to reshape both but it didn't help at all:

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I'm trying to practice this code for ML, but I'm facing some error saying "ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [2788, 1813]"

```
import pandas as pd
dataset = pd.read_csv('/content/spambase.data',header = None)
X = dataset[0:2788]
y = dataset[2788:]

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.svm import SVC

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2,random_state=0)
svc = SVC(kernel='rbf', C=1).fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = svc.predict(X_test)

#importing confusion matrix
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
confusion = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
print('Confusion Matrix\n')
print(confusion)

#importing accuracy_score, precision_score, recall_score, f1_score
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, precision_score, recall_score, f1_score
print('\nAccuracy: {:.2f}\n'.format(accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)))

print('Micro Precision: {:.2f}'.format(precision_score(y_test, y_pred, average='micro')))
print('Micro Recall: {:.2f}'.format(recall_score(y_test, y_pred, average='micro')))
print('Micro F1-score: {:.2f}\n'.format(f1_score(y_test, y_pred, average='micro')))

print('Macro Precision: {:.2f}'.format(precision_score(y_test, y_pred, average='macro')))
print('Macro Recall: {:.2f}'.format(recall_score(y_test, y_pred, average='macro')))
print('Macro F1-score: {:.2f}\n'.format(f1_score(y_test, y_pred, average='macro')))

print('Weighted Precision: {:.2f}'.format(precision_score(y_test, y_pred, average='weighted')))
print('Weighted Recall: {:.2f}'.format(recall_score(y_test, y_pred, average='weighted')))
print('Weighted F1-score: {:.2f}'.format(f1_score(y_test, y_pred, average='weighted')))

from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
print('\nClassification Report\n')
print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred, target_names=['Class 1', 'Class 2', 'Class 3']))
```

Comment: Can you show the complete error output you obtain? Your error is in the `fit` function?

Comment: ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-e40b971706fb> in <module>()
      7 from sklearn.svm import SVC
      8 
----> 9 X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2,random_state=0)
     10 svc = SVC(kernel='rbf', C=1).fit(X_train, y_train)
     11 y_pred = svc.predict(X_test) ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [2788, 1813] @AlexSerraMarrugat

Answer (score 1):

**You have a mistake defining your X and y**.

You have taken for X, the first 2788 **rows**, and for y, you have taken from the **row** 2788 to the end (a total rows of 1813). I repeat, you are taking **rows** instead of columns!!!

To define X you should do something like that:

```
X=df.iloc[:, :2788]
y=df.iloc[:, 2788:]

y=df.iloc["name"] #You can define the output y like this too if you have the name of the columns
```

The first ":" means your are taking all the rows.

Check every pass. When you have defined your X and y, print the len of these variables. They have to be the same.

Comment: No, I don't have a column's names. Its still shows an error.@AlexSerraMarrugat

Comment: Give more information please. You have the same error? Print len(X) and len(y). What you obtain?

Comment: Print len(X) and len(y)                                                                                                  2788
1813 But after using iloc it still showing an error ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [2788, 1813]@AlexSerraMarrugat

Comment: Gautam, only execute the first 4 lines of code. You can only execute the other lines when the len of X and len y is the same. Can you plot the shape of the dataset please? And please, copy this output in your question editing it please. Then we will be able to see how many columns and row do you have